# Is this sentence correct? "We buy cars for cash "

Tags: grammaticality

Is this sentence correct?

> We buy cars for cash.

I read it on a sign outside a car lot. I assume the intent is to say they pay cash for cars but can it also mean they are buying cars in order to get cash?

Comment: It just means they pay cash for cars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, you're correct. But since rules of sociolinguistic communication (see [Grices' maxims](https://effectiviology.com/principles-of-effective-communication/)) imply that the most obvious meaning is the one that they intend to communicate, the sentence is perfectly acceptable with its intended meaning.

This isn't something that works because of grammatical rules but sociolinguistic ones.

Comment: One can parse this so that it's grammatically correct. "Cars " is the object of the verb "buy" and "for cash" is an adverb phrase modifying the verb. It tells you how the buying happens.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that it isn't grammatically correct. It is, of course. But if you're going to parse it, you would need to consider both possible meanings and that "for cash" might not only tell you _how_ the buying happens but instead _why_ it happens.